# How to Upload Multiple files Concurrently in Remoting

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0, remoting

I am doing Projects in remoting , i easily send/receive  single files from a client.but
i don't know how to send multiple files concurrently from a client.can anyone help me with this.

please give somelinks i will feed on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remoting supports concurrent remote calls, so all you have to do is create several threads and make each of them send a single file.

Comment: This may be a concurrency problem in the server object. That object should take into account that in may receive more than one concurrent call.